# Can't find Contact Block

Tags: blocks, contact-us, magento2.4.2

I'm having trouble finding where exactly the Contact-page is located in a shop I got handed down.
There is a Block called 'Contact Us info' saved in the Admin Frontend Portion of Content->Blocks, however that is not the text that is currently being used for the Contact-page.

My next guess was that there might a template somewhere in the custom theme, that is overwriting the existing block. Searching the text that is being displayed did not help, I did however find a matching text in the translation folder of the theme at least (but that doesn't help in finding the original text).

Is there any way to debug this? Or maybe reset it completely so I can just use the block that is in the admin-frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the main template and layout of the contact page can be found in '**vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend**'

If you use a custom theme, check in '**app/design**' if you override the contact module

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find it in the Vendor folder.
Do you by any chance have a hunch why that file does not match up with the block set up in the admin-frontend? is there a way to resynchronize this?

Comment: The block is a custom area that you can include anywhere you want. In the case of CMS pages, you can include it in the Custom Layout. In the case of PHTMLs, you must enter them manually.

`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('contact_custom_block_after')->toHtml();?>`

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!